# Can a diode fail if we increase the current?

Tags: diodes

What happens to the diode at the following circuit if we decrease the value of the resistor? Using Ohm's law, we can find that the current which flows the circuit will increase. Can the diode fail at some point due to the increased value of the current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkY1SX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, of course. 1n4148, first page of datasheet, continuous Absolute Maximum Forward Current is 300mA. Repetitive peaks, peak surge, and other values are also in the datasheet.

Comment: Of course! Read the datasheet for the diode.

Comment: Yes it can fail, and it can fail both as a short or open.

Comment: This is a dumb question since it's directly answered in the datasheet.  Besides, how can you even imagine something might not fail eventually when you run higher and higher current thru it. Duh!

Comment: @OlinLathrop please go easy on the beginners, he or she might never even have heard of 'forward voltage' etc.

Comment: @user: Even a cursory look at the datasheet would have revealed that term.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

For the diode mentioned in the question, there is a limitation on the power it is allowed to dissipate and still function normally. Below table mentions the parameters which come into picture.

[image]

If there is a current of say 0.7 A, then the approximate power dissipated by the diode is 0.7 A * 1.4 V, which is about **1 W**.

[image]

The thermal resistance, says that there will be a rise in temperature of 300 deg. Celsius for every Wattage dissipated by the diode. This temperature is way higher than allowed junction temperature of 175 deg. Celsius:

[image]

After certain time, the diode may fail short or open but **there will be a permanent damage**.

Even if temperature of diode is not allowed to rise, i doubt, the 1 W of power dissipation crosses the datasheet specification of maximum power dissipation which is limited to 500 mW.

The diode may fail SHORT first, shorts itself to power supply, due to excessive heat, may melt and finally fail OPEN.

*Note: All images are from the datasheet of [1N4148 diode](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/1N/1N4148.pdf).*

Answer (score 0):

The diode datasheet is your friend here. It will specify the forward current carrying capabilities of the diode.

At high currents the diode forward voltage will increase with increased current. The internal body resistance of the diode will cause a temperature rise as the power level increases to the point that the silicon structure can no longer withstand the torture and will either melt or fuse its lead junctions.